# WPF (.NET Core 3), Change Background Color Of Editable Combobox?

Tags: wpf

Building my first application using WPF, and stuggling to figure out how to easily style the text input portion of a ComboBox.

I am trying to set the padding, font size, background color, and foreground color of the portion indicated with the red "arrow" below.

[image: Image of area needing changed]

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="URLScanner.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:URLScanner"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="URL Scanner" Height="600" Width="800" Opacity="80" Background="#2b2b2b" Foreground="#ffffff" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffdddddd"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff1e1e1e"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ff000000" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 6, 10, 6" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <ComboBox x:Name="UrlComboBox" IsEditable="True" Margin="20,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="740" Style="{StaticResource DarkControl}">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
            </ComboBox.Resources>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ComboBox has also a new TextBoxStyle property. You can use it to define a custom style for the TextBox inside an editable ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UrlComboBox" IsEditable="True" Margin="20,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="740" Style="{StaticResource DarkControl}">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffdddddd"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff1e1e1e"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ff000000" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 6, 10, 6" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.TextBoxStyle>
        </ComboBox>
```

Update:
Sorry, the above code only work on UWP, please ignore it.
I found the link could help:
[how can i set the background color of the TextBox in an editable ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663595/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-of-the-textbox-in-an-editable-combobox)

Comment: Tried the linked solution, was a disaster that just broke all the styling and then the dropdown just stopped working.   I don't understand why it is so complicated.  :-(

Comment: @eat-sleep-code, I think you have to modify its default ControlTemplate. You can get Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015/2017/2019 to render the default control template by right-click on the ComboBox control in design mode and select "Edit a template"->"Edit a copy. After that you can change what you want

Comment: Yeah, tried that added a bunch to my XAML, but without changes didn't seem to work correct anymore.  Will try again.